# access IBOutlet button from other view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I need to access and change the title of a button that exists on another view controller.   Is this possible? If so, How can I accomplish this?

ViewController 1:

```
Class Home: UIViewController
{
   @IBOutlet  weak var testBTN: UIButton!
}
```

ViewController 2:

```
Home.testBTN // does not work I can't access the button from here
```

I think I found the solution in objective C but I dont know how to accomplish this in swift 
[Access IBOutlet from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594183/access-iboutlet-from-another-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VC 2 (send notification):

```
let updateNotificationString = "com.yourcompany.yourapp.updatebutton"
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(updateNotificationString, object: self)
```

VC 1 (receive and update):

In viewDidLoad:

```
let updateNotificationString = "com.yourcompany.yourapp.updatebutton"
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateButton", name: updateNotificationString, object: nil)
```

Then create a function:

```
func updateButton() {
    testBTN.setTitle("New Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```