# How can I disable a button from another class?

Tags: ios, swift, class, button, uiviewcontroller

I have two UIViewControllers with two buttons.

How can I disable the second button from the first class/UIViewController?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34182663/8403513

Answer (score 2):

Class ViewController 1

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBAction func btn1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Disable"), object: nil)
}
```

}

Class ViewController 2

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController2.disableBtn), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Disable"), object: nil)
}
@IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!
@objc func disableBtn() {
    btn2.isEnabled = false
}
```

}